# How do I add a License Agreement to an AIR application installer?

Tags: actionscript-3, installation, air, flash-builder

I developed an AIR Application, and now i want to add one of those License Text Frames to the install process.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i've done is wrap the .air installer inside a native installer.  for example, on Mac OS X, you could use the application [DMG Canvas](http://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas/) (free, $15 donationware), which includes an EULA feature, to create a .dmg for the .air installer.  i'm sure a similar approach could be taken for Windows as well.

of course, though, this method isn't ideal for simple AIR cross-platformability, but in my case, and perhaps in yours, i had to package AIR native installers anyway since i was using native processes in my application so adding this extra EULA step wasn't so much of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I am seeing, this isn't possible.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install.html

It doesn't look like there is a mechanism to show and have the user accept an end user license agreement at installation. I will dig around some more and update this answer if I find something.

What you could do instead is show the license agreement on the first run of the application and do not allow them to continue if they do not accept.  You would also need to store the acceptance so you don't show it again, etc.